# load certificate in WP7

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, cryptography

in WP7 I Tried to load certificate to get a public key from it and I use this

```
X509Certificate x509 = null;
x509 = X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(CertificateFilePath);
```

and I got this exception:

> {System.MethodAccessException: Attempt to access the method failed:
>   System.Security.Cryptography.X509Certificates.X509Certificate.CreateFromCertFile(System.String)

any one have an idea about this problem ? there anther way to read cert file in WP7 ?

Answer (score 1):

This is an inherent limitation put in place because your application is running in a sandboxed environment, and therefore is not exactly an app that would be classified as "trusted" by Silverlight standards. To [quote MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.security.cryptography.x509certificates.x509certificate.createfromcertfile%28v=vs.95%29.aspx):

> This member can be used only by trusted applications. If you try to
>   use this member in a partial-trust application, your code will throw a
>   MethodAccessException exception. This member is security-critical,
>   which restricts its use.

Comment: So how can I made my application trusted ?

or is there another way to read a .cert file in WP7 ?

Comment: Only OEM and specially-approved apps are classified as full-trust. You are limited to the existing sandbox.